# Is this possible with jQuery and Select options?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a list of countries and their area codes in a database. I am trying to auto update a text field with the countries area code when a select option is selected.

ex.

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="CA" code="+1">Canada</option>
    ...
</select>

<input type="text" name="phone" />
```

I need to pass on to the script the value CA and the users need to see Canada. Basically what I'm asking is can I create a new option `code` and have jQuery update the text field that I choose to it.

Is this possible to do? or is there another way I can accomplish this?

**Edit:** "code" is supposed to be the country's area code. So when a user selects Canada for example the text field `phone` gets updated with +1. I know I can just set `value` to +1 and then use `.change()` to update `phone`'s `.val()` but I need the current value to pass on to the script that processes it.

Comment: I think you have to explain your problem a bit better. What's the purpose of `code`?

Comment: code is supposed to be the country's area code. So when a user selects Canada for example the text field phone gets updated with +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use an HTML5 `data-` attribute instead of a custom attribute:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="CA" data-code="+1">Canada</option>
    ...
</select>

<input type="text" name="phone" />
```

and then bind a handler to the `change` event:

```
$('select[name="country"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="phone"]').val($(this).children('option:selected').data('code'));
});
```

or with less jQuery:

```
$('select[name="country"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="phone"]').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-code'));
});
```

Another option would be to have a `country -> code` map in JavaScript

```
var map = {
    'CA': '+1',
    ...
};
```

and then look up the code.

Comment: This is the best solution, in my opinion. `.data('phone')` should be `.data('code')` though

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks!

@AlexPeattie I also noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to assign each element an id.

```
var code = $('#country option:selected').attr('code');
$('#phone').val(code);
```

If "code" doesn't work. Use "title".

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but dos this help?

```
$('select[name=country]').change(function() {

    $('input[name=phone]').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('code'));

    alert('Do something else with this: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[name='country']").change(function() {
    $("input[name='phone']").val($(this).find('option:selected'));
});
```

You can try this. It ties into the select menus change event and then gets the "code" attribute value and sets the text of the input to it.